# Unable to access the .net 6 core web api following msdn documentation (vs code)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, asp.net-web-api, .net-6.0

Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio-code

I am following the below steps in vs code:

```
dotnet new webapi -o TodoApi
cd TodoApi
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory
code -r ../TodoApi

dotnet dev-certs https --trust

Then I click yes in the pop-up window.
```

Now I am trying to do the below:

```
Press Ctrl+F5.
At the Select environment prompt, choose .NET Core.
Select Add Configuration > .NET: Launch a local .NET Core Console App.
In the configuration JSON:
Replace <target-framework> with net6.0.
Replace <project-name.dll> with TodoApi.dll.
Press Ctrl+F5.
In the Could not find the task 'build' dialog, select Configure Task.
Select Create tasks.json file from template.
Select the .NET Core task template.
Press Ctrl+F5.
```

When I press control+F5, the only sane option is `.NET 5+ and .NET Core` so I select it.

This auto generates 2 files:

`launch.json` :

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/net6.0/TodoApi.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "serverReadyAction": {
                "action": "openExternally",
                "pattern": "\\bNow listening on:\\s+(https?://\\S+)"
            },
            "env": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
            },
            "sourceFileMap": {
                "/Views": "${workspaceFolder}/Views"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Attach",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "attach"
        }
    ]
}
```

`tasks.json`:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "args": [
                "build",
                "${workspaceFolder}/TodoApi.csproj",
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        },
        {
            "label": "publish",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "args": [
                "publish",
                "${workspaceFolder}/TodoApi.csproj",
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        },
        {
            "label": "watch",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "args": [
                "watch",
                "run",
                "--project",
                "${workspaceFolder}/TodoApi.csproj"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now if I press control+F5 then the project runs but I don't understand how to access it - http://locahost:5000 doesn't work.

On launch.json file - note that the config name is .NET Core Launch (web) and not .NET: Launch a local .NET Core Console App; so I delete the contents of the launch.json file, select add configuration and choose Launch a .net core console app as follows:

```
{
    "configurations": [
    {
        "name": ".NET Core Launch (console)",
        "type": "coreclr",
        "request": "launch",
        "preLaunchTask": "build",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/net6.0/Todoapi.dll",
        "args": [],
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "console": "internalConsole"
    }
    ]
}
```

Then I delete the tasks.json file and hit control+F5, select configure tasks, select create task.json file from a template, select .net core. This gives me:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "shell",
            "args": [
                "build",
                // Ask dotnet build to generate full paths for file names.
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                // Do not generate summary otherwise it leads to duplicate errors in Problems panel
                "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "silent"
            },
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I press control+F5, the project runs but how do I access it? http://localhost:5000 doesn't work.

The output is:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
You may only use the Microsoft .NET Core Debugger (vsdbg) with
Visual Studio Code, Visual Studio or Visual Studio for Mac software
to help you develop and test your applications.
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Using launch settings from 'C:\Users\Archco\Downloads\TodoApi\Properties\launchSettings.json' [Profile 'TodoApi']...
```

Answer (score 2):

From the linked article:

> In a browser, navigate to https://localhost:/swagger, where  is the randomly chosen port number displayed in the output.

I followed the steps from you question and here's an example output:

[image]

which includes the line with the address:

```
      Now listening on: https://localhost:7074
```

Please note that the interesting part is at *https://localhost:7074/swagger* not just *https://localhost:7074*

Comment: I'm not getting the text in blue font. Can you spot the different in my json file and yours? It shows url for http as well as https.